# Class not found with Php app hosted on Heroku

Tags: soap, php, heroku

I developp a PHP application hosted on Heroku and which use the PHP Toolkit to interact with Force.com.

When I run the app on my computer, it works, data from Salesforce.com are loaded but when I push my app on the Heroku server, I get this error :

> Class 'SoapClient' not found in /app/Soapclient/SfocePartnerClient.php on line 44

Line 44 :

```
class SforceSoapClient extends SoapClient {
  ...
}
```

What have I to configure on Heroku to fix the error please?

Comment: This is file composer.json : 
{
    "name": "developerforce/force.com-toolkit-for-php",
    "description": "A wrapper for the Force.com Web Services SOAP API",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
           "soapclient"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because the soap extension wasn't correctly activated.

I had to create a case to the Heroku support.

Now, it works fine.

Aurélien

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Is it only fixable on their end?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by requiring "ext-soap" in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    }
}
```

Run `composer update` to generate a `composer.lock` file, and push both files to Heroku, or manually deploy from Dropbox via https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/deploy/dropbox